# Is it possible to compile/save a Pandas query for reuse?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if it were possible to store and reuse Pandas queries.

Something like it is done with regular expressions, as in:

```
query_object = pd.DataFrame.query('a > 5 & b < 9')

# mydf1 and mydf2 are two Pandas.Dataframe with numeric columns a and b
res1 = mydf1.query_object() # applies the query to mydf1
res2 = mydf2.query_object() # applies the query to mydf2
```

The only way I found now is to save the query string, which is not bad, but I was wondering if some mechanism like the above exists.

Comment: Your `query_object` is not a special query object, its a normal dataframe, reduced from the original.

Comment: I was thinking of something like `re` where one can compile a regular expression and then run it on different strings. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects . I am not sure that "query object" is the right nomenclature, but that's the gist. I understand that `DataFrame.query` returns a new `DataFrame`, and that's why I was asking if a mechanism similar to `re` was implemented.

Comment: It is, like I described, numexpr does it in the background for you.

Comment: From what I read from the links you put in your answer, I understood that numexpr does it on the specific DataFrame on which the query is called. If I got it right, the query would be compiled for a specific DataFrame, with no optimization done if I wanted to run it on different data. Your answer on writing a function is a great solution for reusability (and reduces risks of errors) with minimal code overhead.

Comment: No, the query string is compiled and cached and then evaluated for the dataframe. The compilation and caching is indepedendent of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to, you can monkey patch `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
def custom_query(self):
    return self.query('a > 5 & b < 9')
pd.DataFrame.custom_query = custom_query

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10),
                   'b': range(10)})

df.custom_query()
```

output:

```
   a  b
6  6  6
7  7  7
8  8  8
```

**Warning: This is not necessarily recommended and might have unexpected consequences…**

Might be best to just save the query as string and use `.query(saved_string)`

edit, custom query with options:

```
def custom_query(self, option=None):
    if option == 'big_a':
        return self.query('a > 5')
    return self.query('a > 5 & b < 9')

pd.DataFrame.custom_query = custom_query

df.custom_query() # 'a > 5 & b < 9'
df.custom_query('big_a') # 'a > 5'
```

Comment: Yes this is almost it. I suspect this approach would mean that the query itself is always fixed. Anyway, looks like that's the right answer :)

Comment: Well, if the query is not fixed, then maybe you just reinvented… `query`? You could use shortcuts, I'll provide a example.

Comment: right, I would have to save a function for each query, which is not bad, but I don't know if it would be clearer or help me make fewer mistakes. I still think the `saved_string` would be enough. As in `filter_1`, `filter_2` and so on

Comment: no, you could have all options in the single function, but again you could do the same with a dictionary `queries = {'biga': 'a>5', 'smalla': 'a<5'} ; df.query(queries['biga'])`

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: there is no point in saving "a compiled" version of the query. Just store the query string in a variable.

Explanation:

Pandas uses `numexpr` by default for evaluating the string you pass to `DataFrame.query` using the `DataFrame` columns as namespace for the evaluation. Same goes for `DataFrame.eval`:

- https://github.com/pydata/numexpr
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval

`numexpr` compiles the expression to machine code and evaluates it. `numexpr` caches the compiled code, so using the same expression a second time is optimized without you having to do anything.

Edit: If you need to run the same query on many dataframes, it makes sense to define a function for reusability, testability and readability, e.g. like this (use a name for the function that actually tells what is queried):

```
def query_ab_valid(df):
    return df.query("a > 5 & b < 9")
```

Comment: Would it be optimized even if I use it on another dataframe? I asked this question because in my case I would have about 10 dataframes per query. Right now this is done with `query_string1`, `query_string2` and so on (about 5 groups of dataframes).

Comment: @MaxNoe I could eventually see an advantage when you do hands on exploratory work, it might be more convenient to type `df.shortcut(1)` than `df.query('complex query #1')`… but honestly I would definitely **not** encourage it

Comment: alright, it seems that 1) Pandas has no built in method to do this, 2) the best method seems to be to save the query string, 3) other methods seem not to be worth the hassle. I'll close this in a few days, thanks everyone!

Comment: You keep talking about the "query object". `DataFrame.query` just returns a new `DataFrame`, not any kind of special "query object" (or nothing if you use it with the `inplace=True` option.

If you have a fixed query that you need to run on many dataframes, define a function that applies that query to a dataframe, added to the answer.